# Skipping the operation by pressing TAB?

Tags: pascal

I want to realize the possibility that when the program starts the user can enter his coordinates, and also he could skip this paragraph by pressing `<TAB>`. When you click on the program, the program should go to the random coordinate check, that is, to what costs the until `(ch = $ 9)`; but it does not work for me. Tell me, please, how can I fix the code?

```
    uses crt, graphabc;
var
  x,y: array[1..16] of real;
  s:array[1..16] of char;
  i,p,t,w,f,c:integer;
  z:string;
const
  a=14;
  b=29;
  r=27;
  procedure ReadKey(ch : char);
begin
 SetWindowSize(840, 600);
  randomize;
  t:=0;
  w:=10;
  f:=0;

Coordinate.Origin:=new Point(20,120);
  for i:=1 to 15 do 
      begin
 if i=1 then
    begin
    if (ch = $9) then begin
    Coordinate.Origin:=new Point(0,0);
    line(8, 8, 260, 8);
    line(8, 30, 260, 30);
    line(8, 8, 8, 30);
    line(260, 8, 260, 30);
    TextOut(15, 10, 'Enter your coordinates through a space');
    Coordinate.Origin:=new Point(10,110);
    readln(x[1],y[1]);
    end;

    until(ch = $9);

    end;
        s[i]:=chr(64+i);
        x[i+1]:=(-30+(34+30)*random);
        y[i+1]:=(-35+(34+35)*random);
        writeln(s[i],'(', x[i]:3:0, ';',y[i]:3:0,')');
        if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
           (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=-4) or
           (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<=round(-b/2)) or
           (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<=round(b/2))
        then t:=t+1;
        if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]>r*r) then begin 
           TextOut(65, f, ' - point outside the boundary of a circle');
           f:=f+16;
        end
           else if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]=r*r) then begin 
              TextOut(65, f, ' - the point hit the outer border');
              f:=f+16; 
           end
           else if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<-14) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<round(-b/2)) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]=round(b/2))
                   then begin
                        TextOut(65, f, ' - the point hit the inner border');
                        f:=f+16;
                        end
                   else begin
                        TextOut(65, f, ' - the point fell outside the internal border');
                        f:=f+16;
                        end
         end;
```

Comment: ch is filled nowhere?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort  most likely it should be filled in this line readln (x [1], y [1]);

Comment: No, that only fills x[1] and y[1]

Comment: You have declared a procedure `procedure ReadKey(ch : char);` which you need to rename, because the name collides with the built in function `function ReadKey: Char;` which is the one you should call at a suitable point: (`ch := ReadKey;`) to get a character from the user. You then also have to declare `ch: Char;` in the `var` section.

Comment: You can read about `function ReadKey: Char;` [**here**](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/readkey.html).

Comment: Is this still an open question?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, Yes, I will be glad to hear at least some ideas

Comment: Well, I suggested something a few comments ago. Have you made the changes?